# SQLAlchmey: How to filter by timedelta and a date in a query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and I want to add 1 day to the datetime in a table, how can I do this?

E.g: I want to select user accounts older than 1 day

```
date = datetime.now()
User.query.filter(User.created_date + timedelta(days=1) < date)).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the equivalent? I mean

```
User.created_date + timedelta(days=1) < date
```

is equivalent to:

```
User.created_date < date - timedelta(days=1)
```